# How are the packages installed with 'package-install'(elpa) in Emacs loaded?

Tags: emacs, emacs24, elpa

I have installed some packages by using elpa in my Emacs, but how are they loaded when launching Emacs?

Answer (score 1):

`package-install` is a part of `package.el` -- which You can see with `describe-function`. From `package.el` documentation:

```
;; At activation time we will set up the load-path and the info path,
;; and we will load the package's autoloads.  If a package's
;; dependencies are not available, we will not activate that package.
```

So in every package there's a file

```
NAME-autoloads.el
```

and this file is loaded at start up.

The whole package is contained under the `package-user-dir`:

```
(setq package-user-dir "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/package-install")
(require 'package)
```

Each package also contains `NAME-pkg.el` with package version and description. For example here're files related to `tabbar` package:

```
package-install             # that's my package-user-dir
└── tabbar-2.0.1            # each package dir is in the separate dir
    ├── tabbar-autoloads.el # this file is loaded at start up
    ├── tabbar.el           # the package itself. In this case it is just a single file
    └── tabbar-pkg.el       # information about the package for package managment
```

To quote the manual: [39.1.1 Summary: Sequence of Actions at Startup](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html#Startup-Summary):

> 15. If package-enable-at-startup is non-nil, it calls the function package-initialize to activate any optional Emacs Lisp package that has been installed.

`package-initialize` is then calls `package-activate` which in turn calls `package-activate-1` which ends with loading `NAME-autoload.el`:

```
(load (expand-file-name (concat name "-autoloads") pkg-dir) nil t)
```